# Confusion on derivative of conditional expectation: difference between function and random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(X,Y)$ be two random variables. Suppose that the expectation *function* of $Y$ conditional on $X=x$ is
\[
\operatorname {E}[Y | X = x] = g(x).
\]
Therefore the following derivative is well defined
\[
\frac{d \operatorname {E}[Y | X = x]}{dx} = g'(x),
\]
and $g'(x)$ is the marginal change in the conditional expected value of $Y$ with respect of a small change in $x$.

The conditional expectation (as a *random variable*) of $Y$ conditional on $X$ is defined as
\[
\operatorname {E}[Y | X] = g(X).
\]
Is the derivative with respect of the random variable $X$
\[
\frac{d \operatorname {E}[Y | X]}{dX} = g'(X),
\]
actually well defined? What is the difference between $g'(X)$ and $g'(x)$ ?

Comment: I am not convinced $g’(x)$ is well-defined.

Comment: I always took your two ways of writing the expectation as being numerically equivalent which is all that a statistician would be interested in. The specfic value of X is  being left out in the second one but, as far as I know ( or thought ), that's just notation. It's implied.